# Getting a 404 error when the page exists

Tags: html, swift, post, http-status-code-404, vapor

I am making a post request to a server with an HTML form. When I press the submit button for the form I get a 404 page does not exist error. However, if I go to the URL through directly typing in the address bar, I get the error I should be getting from the server (400 invalid request).

Here is my HTML (note I am using leaf):

```
#extend("base")

#export("head") {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/skeleton.css">
}

#export("body") {
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/admin/new-post" method="POST">
            <div class="row" style="padding: 25px 0 0 0;">
                <div class="six columns form-group">
                    <label for="email">Usernam</label>
                    <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="six columns form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="u-full-width" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" anem="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
            <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

And my server code (Swift):

```
import Vapor
import HTTP

final class AdminController {

    func addRoutes(to drop: Droplet) {
        let admin = drop.grouped("admin")
        drop.get("login", handler: login)
        admin.get("new-post", handler: newPost)
    }

    func login(_ request: Request)throws -> ResponseRepresentable {
        return try drop.view.make("admin-login", [])
    }

    func newPost(_ request: Request)throws -> ResponseRepresentable {
        guard let cred = request.auth.header?.basic else {
            throw Abort.badRequest
        }
        do {
            try request.auth.login(cred)
            return try drop.view.make("new-post", [])
        } catch {
            return Response(redirect: "/login?login=failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting a 404 error?

The web framework I am using is Vapor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, have a look at your droplet, you add a new route with a *GET*-Request `new-post` but your form try *POST* to `new-post`, for sure that will fail.

Try to change

`admin.get("new-post", handler: newPost)`

to

`admin.post("new-post", handler: newPost)`